# Why can I replace this direct sum isomorphism with an equality?

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, homology-cohomology

From Rotman's **Algebraic Topology**

> Theorem:  For all $n \ge 0, $ $$\tilde H_n(X) \approx H_n(\tilde S_*(X), \partial)$$ where $\tilde H$ means reduced homology groups.
>
> Proof:  There's a short exact sequence $0 \rightarrow \text {ker } \tilde \partial_0 \rightarrow S_0(X) \xrightarrow{\tilde \partial_0} \tilde S_{-1}(X) \rightarrow 0$.  If $\alpha \in S_0(X)$ satisfies $\tilde \partial_0(\alpha) = 1,$ then it is easy to see that $S_0(X) = \text{ker } \tilde \partial_0 \oplus \langle \alpha \rangle$ and $\langle \alpha \rangle \approx \Bbb Z.$  But $\tilde \partial_0 \partial_1 = 0 $ implies that $B_0(X) = \text{im } \partial_1 \subset \text{ker } \tilde \partial_0$.  Since $S_0(X) = Z_0(X), $ we have:
>
> $(*) \space H_0(X) = S_0(X)/B_0(X) = (\text{ker } \tilde \partial_0 \oplus \langle \alpha \rangle) / B_0(X) $ $\approx (\text{ker }\tilde \partial _0 / B_0(X)) \oplus \Bbb Z = \tilde H_0(X) \oplus \Bbb Z.$

The author then footnotes:

> This is a special case of a more general result:  If $0 \rightarrow K \rightarrow G \rightarrow F \rightarrow 0$ is exact with $(K \rightarrow G)$ an inclusion with $F$ free abelian, then $G = K \oplus F'$, where $F' \approx F$.  Here we present a proof of this special case.  If $x \in \text{ker} \tilde \partial_0 \cap \langle \alpha \rangle,$ then $x = m\alpha$ and $\tilde \partial_0(x) = 0 = m$, hence $x=0$; if $\gamma \in S_0(X),$ then $\tilde \partial_0(\gamma)= k$, say, and so $\gamma = (\gamma - k \alpha) + k \alpha \in \text{ker } \tilde \partial_0 + \langle  \alpha \rangle$.

But I'm a little confused on the notation here.  I see that in the footnote the author shows that $S_0(X) = \text{ker } \tilde \partial_0 + \langle \alpha \rangle \approx \text{ker } \tilde \partial_0 \oplus \langle \alpha \rangle$, which implies that $S_0(X) \approx \text{ker } \tilde \partial_0 \oplus \langle \alpha \rangle$.  But in the proof of the theorem the author states that explicitly $S_0(X)$ is exactly equal to  $\text{ker } \tilde \partial_0 \oplus \langle \alpha \rangle$.

What exactly am I missing here?  The footnote seems to indicate a direct sum, along with the line in the partial proof.  But the proof in the footnote seems to only prove that it's they're isomorphic and not equal.

Comment: I think the confusion comes from the $\text{ker } \tilde \partial_0 + \langle \alpha \rangle \approx \text{ker } \tilde \partial_0 \oplus \langle \alpha \rangle$. It is a canonical isomorphism which can be treated as an equality with no issue. It can even be a literal equality depending on how you view direct sums.

Comment: @CaptainLama Can you elaborate on this?  I'm not understanding why there will be no issue.

In the part of the proof marked (*) (added now), the third equation should be nonsense as $B_0(X)$ is not a subset of $\text{ker } \tilde \partial_0 \oplus \langle \alpha \rangle$ and therefor one should not be able to form $\text{ker } \tilde \partial_0 \oplus \langle \alpha \rangle / B_0(X)$.

Comment: @OliverG I'm not sure where exactly your $S_0(X)\approx \ker \tilde \partial_0 \oplus \langle \alpha \rangle$ comes from? The footnote clearly implies that $S_0(X)=\ker \tilde \partial_0 \oplus \langle \alpha \rangle$ with $\langle \alpha\rangle\approx \tilde S_{-1}(X)$. Also note that in this context "$\oplus$" stands for the **internal** direct product.

Comment: @freakish If $A+B = G$ and $A \cap B = \{0\}$, then $A+B \approx A \oplus B$.  Where $A+B$ means internal direct product (sum operation) and $A \oplus B$ means external direct product.  The foonote says it is a special case of "$\oplus$", but then proceeds to prove "$+$" by showing exactly that $S_0(X) = \text{ker } \tilde \partial_0  + \langle \alpha \rangle$, and is proved by showing it is an internal direct product via sums of elements.

Comment: The author then says $S_0(X) = \text{ker } \tilde \partial_0 \oplus \langle \alpha \rangle$ after having just proved $S_0(X) = \text{ker } \tilde \partial_0  + \langle \alpha \rangle$.  Since internal direct sums are isomorphic and not equal to external direct sums, they cannot be equal groups.  If "$A \oplus B$" stands for internal direct product, what does "$A + B$" stand for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's recall few definitions:

1. If $A,B\subseteq G$ are subgroups (more generally submodules) then $A+B=\{a+b\ |\ a\in A, b\in B\}$. This is a subgroup (submodule) if $G$ is abelian. This is not the internal direct product/sum. It is just a sum of subgroups.
2. If $A,B\subseteq G$ are subgroups of an abelian group $G$ then we say that $G$ is the internal direct product/sum of $A$ and $B$ if $G=A+B$ and $A\cap B=0$. In this case we write $G=A\oplus B$.
3. If $A,B$ are (arbitrary) groups then their external direct product/sum is defined as the Cartesian product $A\times B$ as a set with pointwise group addition $(a,b)+(a',b'):=(a+a', b+b')$. In this case we also write $A\oplus B$.

All of that is the standard notation. And there's a theorem that says that if $G=A\oplus B$ is the internal direct product then $G\simeq A\oplus B$ as the external direct product. And vice versa, the external direct product $A\oplus B$ induces internal by taking $A\times 0$ and $0\times B$.

Clearly the author uses both 1. and 2. in the footnote and $S_0(X)=\ker\tilde\partial_0\oplus \langle \alpha\rangle$ part. He then switches to the external direct product with $(\ker\tilde\partial_0\oplus \langle \alpha\rangle)/B_0(X)\simeq (\ker\tilde\partial_0/B_0(X))\oplus \langle \alpha\rangle$ isomorphism: he uses internal on the left side and external on the right side.

I agree that this is confusing, he is juggling with both terms. But since internal and external direct products are pretty much the same thing I suppose we can forgive him this nuance.

Comment: If $\oplus$ means internal direct sum, then how can $(\text{ker } \tilde \partial_0 \oplus \langle \alpha \rangle) / B_0(X) $ $\approx (\text{ker }\tilde \partial _0 / B_0(X)) \oplus \langle \alpha \rangle $?

Comment: The author in a second footnote, to $(\text{ker } \tilde \partial_0 \oplus \langle \alpha \rangle) / B_0(X) $ $\approx (\text{ker }\tilde \partial _0 / B_0(X)) \oplus \langle \alpha \rangle $, proves this by using $\oplus$ as an external direct product by saying: Let $B_i \subset A_i$ and $\theta : A_1 \oplus A_2 \rightarrow (A_1 / B_1) \oplus (A_2/ B_2)$ by $(a_1, a_2) \mapsto (a_1 + B_1, a_2 + B_2)$ and to apply the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: This seems to imply that he is treating $(\text{ker } \tilde \partial_0 \oplus \langle \alpha \rangle)$ in the line $(\text{ker } \tilde \partial_0 \oplus \langle \alpha \rangle) / B_0(X) $ $\approx (\text{ker }\tilde \partial _0 / B_0(X)) \oplus \langle \alpha \rangle $ as an external direct product

Comment: To be specific, in the footnote he is proving $(A_1 \oplus A_2) / (B_1 \oplus B_2) \approx (A_1 / B_1) \oplus (A_2 / B_2)$ as external direct sums\products.

Comment: @OliverG well, you're right, he is using the external direct product as well. Precisely in the part you've mentioned. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @OliverG the isomorphism between $(A_1\oplus A_1/(B_1\oplus B_2)$ and $A_1/B_1\oplus A_2/B_2$ also works with internal product on the left and (obviously) external on the right.

Comment: Ah, now it makes sense.  We have $$(\text{ker } \tilde \partial_0 \oplus_{\text{Internal}} \langle \alpha \rangle) / B_0(X) \approx (\text{ker } \tilde \partial_0 \oplus_{\text{External}} \langle \alpha \rangle) / (B_0(X) \oplus_{\text{External}} \{0\})$$ via $(\gamma, k \alpha) + (B_0(X), \{0\}) \mapsto \gamma + k \alpha + B_0(X)$, and the rest follows.